Can't access named credential connecting to another salesforce org
I'm having trouble using a named credential to connect to another salesforce org. I get the error "We couldn't access the credential(s). You might not have the required permissions, or the external credential doesn't exist"
I have created:

A connected app with refresh_token and full scopes in the target org.
An auth provider in our source org, with Salesforce provider type with the correct cliend key and secret
An external credential with oAuth 2.0 authentication and Browser flow, using the created auth provider
A Named Principal, which I already authorized logging in to the other org (authentication status = Configured)
A named credential, using the created external credentials and with the url being the instance url of the target org

First I learned about the named principal so I updated the callback url in the connected app of the target org and could authorize that with no problem. Then, I learned that not having the target url configured in Remote Site settings could cause this, but then I added it and still I have the same error. Am I missing something else? Any help is appreciated.
EDIT:
I can't add my named credential to Named Credential Access in the System Administrator profile:


Why not add that as the answer so this question clearly has an answer.

Sorry everyone, my mistake. I assigned the external credential principal's permission to the wrong profile (for some reason there are two Administrator profiles in our org and I assigned it to the default System Administrator when a custom one is used). With that permission assigned correctly, the named credentails works as expected.
